# Dispatcher.Invoke() wpf

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

i got the following windows form  come:

```
if (richTextBoxReceive.InvokeRequired)
            {
                richTextBoxReceive.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>
                    richTextBoxReceive.AppendText(string.Format("{0}\n\r", msg))));
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBoxReceive.AppendText(string.Format("{0}\n\r", msg));
            }



 i am using this code in WPF aplication and when i replace whit 

 if (richTextBoxReceive.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                richTextBoxReceive.Dispatcher.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>
                    richTextBoxReceive.AppendText(string.Format("{0}\n\r", msg))));
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBoxReceive.AppendText(string.Format("{0}\n\r", msg));
        }
```

im getting 3 errors:

1)Error : WpfApplication1.MethodInvoker does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument

2)Error : Argument 1: cannot convert from 'WpfApplication1.MethodInvoker to System.Delegate

3)Error : The best overloaded method match for System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Delegate, params object[]) has some invalid arguments

I am new to WPF... i hope i didn t put any dumb question , if u got a solution for my problem pleas help me 
Thanks very much !

Comment: What are you using this for, BTW?

Comment: using it in a function to add a message in a richtextbox

Comment: My question is what type of application or UI are you trying to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
richTextBoxReceive.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(()=> ...));
```

Comment: @DaniDărăban remove the MethodInvoker thing. I don't know what that is, but WPF does not need that.